# MySQL: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, database

Please help me, what's wrong with my query. I need to update **land_superseded_assessment** table from **land_propertyassessment** from different database.

```
UPDATE erptax_db.land_superseded_assessment lsa
    INNER JOIN erptax_dumalinao.land_propertyassessment lp
    ON lp.landinfo_arpno = lsa.old_arp_no
SET
    lsa.old_assessed_value=(SUM(lp.landpropertyassessment_assessmentvalue))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
UPDATE erptax_db.land_superseded_assessment lsa
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT landinfo_arpno, SUM(landpropertyassessment_assessmentvalue) as total
    FROM erptax_dumalinao.land_propertyassessment
    GROUP BY landinfo_arpno
) lp ON lsa.old_arp_no = lp.landinfo_arpno

SET
  lsa.old_assessed_value=lp.total
```

Comment: Welcome @HerbertYeo